# NPM is not able to install

Tags: node.js, npm

NPM is throwing errors when i try to install any app. The errors are as below -

---

```
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ember-cli"
npm ERR! node v4.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.2
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package grunt-contrib-clean@0.6.0 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib@0.11.0 wants grunt-contrib-clean@~0.5.0
```

---

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Shaz

Comment: by saying "I try to install any app", you mean by installing any package I assume?

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right.. in fact in my post above I was trying to install the Ember Cli package but could not and similarly same is the case with other npm packages.. I am not able to install them

Comment: Try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920571/cant-install-any-packages-in-node-js-using-npm-install
I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have gotten yourself into the situation described in this [issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4749). And, that is that an invalid module was linked with the `npm link` command.

After reading through there, the solution that I would try is one of the ones provided by Github user, [sam-github](https://github.com/sam-github). And, that solution is to uninstall everything that you have globally installed with npm and then try to only reinstall what is necessary.

To discover what is installed globally by npm, you can use this command:
`npm ls -g`

And then, to uninstall a module that is installed globally use this command: `npm uninstall <module-name> -g`

On the other hand, if you have never used the npm link command, then this may not solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Thawna NP and ctlacko ..nothing had seemed to work so I have uninstalled node and npm completely and hope to make a fresh install.. thanks again

Comment: @Shahsayyad if this does work for you, please come back and accept this as the answer so that people who have this problem in the future know where to look.

Comment: I tried various ways to work around my problem but nothing was working.. there were issues with symlinks and wrong paths too .. so I completely removed node and its modules and then reinstalled it with Brew, Then I faced a problem with permissions which after setting it correctly.. everything was back on track .. thanks for you guys help

Answer (score -1):

One of the reason for getting this error is your node version is not a stable one, try using a stable node version,

Use **NVM** to install multiple versions of node and switch between them and test your app.