# NPM install results in 404 when installing angular deps

Tags: node.js, npm

I have the latest node.js 8.x and npm 5.6.0 installed. When trying to do a `npm install`, I constantly get the following error:

> npm ERR! code E404
>
> npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @angular/router@5.2.0

The module that fails is different every time I retry the installation, but most typically it's `@angular/forms@5.2.0`, `@angular/animations@5.2.0` and `@angular/platform-browser@5.2.0`

- I do have a working internet connection
- I have run `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`.
- I deleted the `node_modules` folder
- I have deleted the cache: `npm cache clean --force`
- An `npm search` does find the module:

> C:\windows\system32>npm search @angular/router
>
> NAME                      | DESCRIPTION          | AUTHOR          | DATE       | VERSION  | KEYWORDS
>
> @angular/router           | Angular -
>   the…       | =angular        | 2018-04-16 | 5.2.10   | angular router

What else can be wrong?

Here is the package.json for completeness:

```
{
  "name": "App",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --env=scapp",
    "build-local": "ng build --env=dev",
    "build-nonevis": "ng build --env=nonevis",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "lint-fix": "ng lint --fix",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "5.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "9.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "2.0.1",
    "@types/arcgis-js-api": "^4.4.0",
    "@types/node": "9.4.0",
    "angular2-esri-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "cerialize": "^0.1.18",
    "chart.js": "2.7.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "esri-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "fullcalendar": "3.7.0",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "nanoscroller": "0.8.7",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "5.3.4",
    "primeng": "5.2.0",
    "quill": "1.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.1",
    "karma": "1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.3.0",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "3.2.0",
    "tslint": "5.7.0",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install any packages in Node.js using "npm install"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920571/cant-install-any-packages-in-node-js-using-npm-install)

Comment: npm does not seem to be down, so I don't think this is related

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by a local file `.npmrc` which contained the line `always-auth = true`. Removing this line resolved the issue. I have no idea how a 404 error is related to authentication, but noticed that after I switched to a mirror registry, it suddenly reported E401 instead of E404 like the official registry.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, such issue was resolved by adding @latest to the command.

npm install -g @angular/cli@latest