# Reactjs project creating while react-dev-utils not found

Tags: reactjs, npm

I had created reactjs project first I had installed globally create react app

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

next, I try to project creation. am using this command

```
create-react-app react-firebase
```

while installing i had faced npm ERR! 404 Not Found: react-dev-utils@^5.0.2

**error:**

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: react-dev-utils@^5.0.2
```

How to fix it...

Comment: Can you try doing `npm install --save-dev react-dev-utils`

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna thank u i will try  Is it install globally or project folder inside

Comment: Inside the project diretory.

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna this error throws while project creating so I can't install in project directory

Comment: You should try `npm install -g react-dev-utils`

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna same issue came

Comment: Can you find `react-dev-utils` in the output of this ? `npm list -g`

Comment: @ragu you won't get same issue can you paste your console output in pastebin.com after running `npm install -g react-dev-utils `

Comment: I have the same issue. 
@KedarnagMukanahallipatna I do not see react-dev-utils in the output of npm list -g

Comment: Can you try this ? `npm init react-app react-firebase`

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna
OUTPUT: 

C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm init react-app react-firebase
This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.
It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sensible defaults.

See `npm help json` for definitive documentation on these fields
and exactly what they do.

Use `npm install <pkg>` afterwards to install a package and
save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

Press ^C at any time to quit.
package name: (system32)

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna  i used this line npm init react-app react-firebase, same issue came

Comment: I'll take the blame here, as I should have asked you before which OS are you trying it on ? I assumed it was OS X. _This is uncharted territory for me_

Comment: Check, if [this](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/229#issuecomment-308183778) helps.

Comment: This issue is being discussed also on the create-react-app repo (which is the project from which react-dev-utils is published). See here and feel free to add info: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4939

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i tried this `yarn add -g react-dev-utils@https://registry.npmjs.org/react-dev-utils/react-dev-utils-5.0.2.tgz` (remove the "/-/" from the URL) and then run `create-react-app my-app` and it worked.

or if using npm try:

```
npm install -g react-dev-utils@https://registry.npmjs.org/react-dev-utils/react-dev-utils-5.0.2.tgz
```

Comment: it says yarn is not a recognized command.
I'm using windows command prompt

Comment: replace "yarn add" with "npm install". Check my original post for the full command

Comment: react-dev-utils installed. react app created. Thanks for ending all the frustration. I was worried how I was going to go on with learning react without practicing the code.

Comment: You can also update the url in yarn.lock file and remove the dash(-). Worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is npm is not able to find `react-dev-utils` in the registry server. 
you can try different registries as mentioned here

[Can't install any packages in Node.js using "npm install"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920571/cant-install-any-packages-in-node-js-using-npm-install)

then you can solve this installing that package

```
npm install react-dev-utils@^5.0.2  -g
```

Comment: Is it install globally or project folder inside npm install react-dev-utils@^5.0.2 --save

Comment: you can do either way but installing in your project is better

Comment: this error throws while project creating so I can't install in project directory

Comment: npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: react-dev-utils@https://registry.npmjs.org/react-dev-utils/-/react-dev-utils-5.0.2.tgz

this is the output for the cmmand

Comment: try `npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/` and then run it again

Comment: Same error

C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/

C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm install react-dev-utils@^5.0.2  -g
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: react-dev-utils@https://registry.npmjs.org/react-dev-utils/-/react-dev-utils-5.0.2.tgz

Comment: After referring to the link, I tried the command , npm set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/ and got the same output after install command: npm ERR! 404 Not Found: react-dev-utils@https://registry.npmjs.org/react-dev-utils/-/react-dev-utils-5.0.2.tgz

Comment: Even if I try to set the registry with http link, in the error msg it still says the https link is not found

Answer (score 0):

Something has changed in the registries. Explicitly adding the package didn't work for me, but flushing the lock files to remove reference to the old registry path did:

Yarn:

- Delete `yarn.lock`
- Run `yarn`

NPM:

- Delete `package-lock.json`
- Run `npm install`